# "there is no dwarfdump executable defined" Error message

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm attempting to validate an Archive in Xcode 4.4 and am receiving the following error:

"there is no dwarfdump executable defined"

Using Xcode 4.2 the same build passed validation.  Anybody any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this error is common when using Beta/Preview versions of Xcode and thus Preview/Beta versions of Xcode should not be used for releasing code.